# How to get path from msi

Tags: python, windows-installer

Hi, I have created a **MSI** installer using Python in which I am taking a location from user (say **PATH_DIR**). When I try to print this path in a text file executing a Python script at the end of the installation, it does not print the whole path that was taken. The path includes spaces in it. How should I do it so that the whole path is printed?

Comment: Is the property reference enclosed in quotes? This is required for paths which contain spaces.

Comment: yes it is. but still its giving the same problem

Comment: How are you printing the path? Can you give me more details?